# Swipable tabs without using fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, swipe, fragmentpageradapter

I'd like to know if it's possible to adapt my actual tabs to create swipable tabs without using fragments.

Right now I have non-swipable tabs (each tab contain an endless list : NewsList).

Here's the code I use for my non-swipable tabs :

```
tabHost = (TabHost)this.findViewById(R.id.scrollTabs);
// Avant d’ajouter des onglets, il faut impérativement appeler la méthode
    // setup() du TabHost
LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

// Ajoute un onglet pour chaque catégorie de news
tabNewslist = new NewsList[NewsCategory.values().length];
View tabView;

for (int i = 0; i < NewsCategory.values().length; i++) {
    tabView = createTabView(tabHost.getContext(), NewsCategory.getValueAt(i).getName());

    tabNewslist[i] = new NewsList(this, new LinkedList<Item>(), IdUrlRss.NEWSLIST, NewsCategory.getValueAt(i));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(NewsCategory.getValueAt(i).getName()).setIndicator(tabView).setContent(tabNewslist[i]));
}
```

And here's the XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/tabHost"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:fillViewport="true"
                          android:scrollbars="none">                        
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I also tried to create a PagerAdapter for NewsList but I failed.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Fragments?  It's fairly easy to convert over to them.

Comment: What's the easiest way ? I wonder if my endless list view will still work after, I use it everywhere in my app (in some places without tabs)

Comment: Fragments and Activities have similar lifecycles so you can extract the relevant stuff into the correct part of the Fragment.  The only part that can be tricky is then attaching the Fragment to your Activity, but there are tons of examples on doing this.  Just remember that Fragment doesn't have Context so you have to use getActivity() often.

Comment: I also created my own custom activity and I use it everywhere in my app so if I use fragment instead I'll have to change everything and I don't have the time for that :(

Comment: If you're still working on this project: You could convert your Activity into a Fragment and then create a dummy Activity that just contains the Fragment. Then you can use the dummy activity or the fragment to show the list.

Comment: Not working anymore on the project but thanks, I used this to produce swipable tabs easily -> http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, by using either

- [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) or
- extend the [Workspace](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/06/android-ui-pattern-workspaces.html) UI pattern from the android [AOSP launcher package](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/launcher2/Workspace.java)

The second option is better as you can use almost anything as a 'Page' inside the launcher (just like the android homescreen)

That said, it would be much easier to just use fragments and then use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) on it :)

Comment: Could I use ViewPager + View instead of fragments ?

Comment: I think you might be able to do that, check out how the TextView was added to the ViewPager on the bottom of this link http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html